# sorting number based on the similar starting digits

Tags: c#, linq

I have a var allList which contains a list of all the accounts in my tables , I want to order the account ids based on the parent number which the first three digits or four digits, if string have similar starting digits can be next to that,
I have the following data as the output per now

```
101
202
303
404
10111
10122
20211
20222
303211
101112
101222
10111221
42215
10111223
3035422525
1011122121


I want the output to be like this 

101
10111
10122
101112
101222
10111221
10111223
1011122121
202
20211
2022222
2023221
303
303211
3035422525
404
42215
```

I have tried this code, the accountid is string,can we use thenby or trimstrat

```
   allList = allList.OrderBy(x => x.accountId);
```

Comment: The term to research is *natural sort*. Numbers stored as strings are not numbers at all.

Comment: they are string type , orderby we can use but some trick must be there to do the required order came through thenby but I don't know how to use it with this issue

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want something like this:

```
  allList = allList
    .OrderBy(item => item.Length <= 3 ? item : item.Substring(0, 3))
    .ThenBy(item => item.Length)
    .ThenBy(item => item)
    .ToList();
```

Here we sort

- By first `3` digits ("first three digits or four digits"): `101 < 404`
- On tie, by `Length`: `10122 < 101112`
- On tie, by items lexicographically: `10111221 < 10111223`

Comment: thank you for your answer, it worked for the three digits ,101
1-   101
2-   10111
3-   10122   this should be number 4
4-   101112  this should be number 3
5-   101222
6-   1012221
7-   1012223
8-   10111221 this number 5 
9-   10111223  this should be number 7
10- 101222121
11- 1011122121  this should be number 6
12- 202
13- 20211
14- 20222
15- 2022222
16- 2023221
17- 303
18- 303211
19- 3035422525
20- 404
21- 40442215